# Splitting a string based on a pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have long strings such as

`"123 - Footwear, 5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, 9876 - Leisure Products"`

and

`"321 - Apparel & Accessories, 4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases, 187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes"`

I want to split them based on the pattern "a number, a space, a dash, a space, some string until the next number, a space, a dash, a space or end of string". Notice that the string may contain commas, ampersands, '>' and other special characters, so splitting on them will not work. I think there is a way in Python to split based on regular expressions but I have trouble forming that.

I have a very introductory knowledge of regular expressions. I can form a regex for numbers, as well as for alphanumeric strings, but I don't know how to specify "take everything until the next number starts".

---

Update: Expected output:

first case:

`["123 - Footwear", "5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods", "9876 - Leisure Products"]`

second case:

`["321 - Apparel & Accessories", "4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases", "187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes"]`

Comment: I suggest checking out the excellent website http://regular-expressions.info where you can learn much, much more about them and answer your own question.

Comment: Please add an expected result

Comment: @jhole89 did that.

Comment: @TapalGoosal Try [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51534547/3832970). If your categories can contain digits, you can't rely on whitelisting or `\D+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match substrings starting with one or more digits followed with 1+ whitespaces, `-`, 1+ whitespaces and ending with the same pattern or end of string.

```
re.findall(r"\d+\s+-\s+.*?(?=\s*(?:,\s*)?\d+\s+-\s|\Z)", s, re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/atrAgF/2)

**Note**: If the leading number length is more than one, say, it is at least a 2-digit number, you may replace the `\d+` with `\d{2,}`, etc. Adjust as you see fit.

**Regex demo**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+-\s+` - a `-` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the location in string that is followed with...
- `(?=\s*(?:,\s*)?\d+\s+-\s|\Z)` - (a positive lookahead):

  - `\s*(?:,\s*)?\d+\s+-\s` - 0+ whitespaces, an optional substringof a comma and 0+ whitespaces after it, 1+ digits, 1+ whitespaces, `-` and a whitespace
  - `|`  - or
  - `\Z` - end of string

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/OiSwpw):

```
import re

rx = r"\d+\s+-\s+.*?(?=\s*(?:,\s*)?\d+\s+-\s|\Z)"
texts = ["123 - Footwear, 5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, 9876 - Leisure Products", "321 - Apparel & Accessories, 4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases, 187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes"]
for s in texts:
    print("--- {} ----".format(s))
    print(re.findall(rx, s, re.S))
```

Output:

```
--- 123 - Footwear, 5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, 9876 - Leisure Products ---
['123 - Footwear', '5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods', '9876 - Leisure Products']
--- 321 - Apparel & Accessories, 4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases, 187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes ---
['321 - Apparel & Accessories', '4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases', '187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes']
```

Comment: What is `re.S`?

Comment: @TapalGoosal It is the same as `re.DOTALL`, a modifier that makes `.` match line break chars, too. By default, a `.` does not match line breaks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the pattern, first there is some number so we use `[0-9]+` followed by string and special characters like `&` `-` `>`, therefore we can use `[a-zA-Z \-&>]+`:

```
>>> str_ = "123 - Footwear, 5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, 9876 - Leisure Products"
>>> re.findall(r'(?is)([0-9]+[a-zA-Z \-&>,]+)', str_)
['123 - Footwear, ',
 '5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, ',
 '9876 - Leisure Products']
```

Another string you mentioned in OP

```
>>> str_ = "321 - Apparel & Accessories, 4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases, 187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes"
>>> re.findall(r'(?is)([0-9]+[a-zA-Z \-&>,]+)', str_)
['321 - Apparel & Accessories, ', 
 '4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases, ', 
 '187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes']
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a ',' in your regex, when matching special characters ? Such as :  (?is)([0-9]+[a-zA-Z \-&>,]+). This way you'll match items that are behind a comma in the strings given in OP

Comment: The strings may contain commas.

Comment: For the first example I would like the second element in the list to be "5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods".

Comment: Your second string demo results [still include commas](https://ideone.com/LqlqY9).

Answer (score 3):

If numbers appear only at the beginning of each segment of strings, you can do:

```
import re
for s in "123 - Footwear, 5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, 9876 - Leisure Products", "321 - Apparel & Accessories, 4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases, 187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes":
    print(re.findall(r'\d+\D+(?=,\s*\d|$)', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['123 - Footwear', '5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods', '9876 - Leisure Products']
['321 - Apparel & Accessories', '4321 - Apparel & Accessories > Handbags, Wallets & Cases', '187 - Apparel & Accessories > Shoes']
```

This regex pattern uses `\d+` to match numbers first, then uses `\D+` to match non-numbers, and uses lookahead pattern `(?=,\s*\d|$)` to make sure that the non-numbers stops at the point where it's followed by either a comma, some spaces and another number, or the end of the string, so that the resulting match won't include a trailing comma and a space.

Comment: Note that `\s*` at the end makes no sense since `\D+` already consumes all those whitespaces.

Comment: Yes, can you also briefly explain?

Comment: @TapalGoosal Just added some explanations to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it is as simple as just splitting when you encounter a numeric?

```
s = "123 - Footwear, 5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, 9876 - Leisure Products"
re.findall(r'\d+\D+', s) 

['123 - Footwear, ',
 '5678 - Apparel, Accessories & Luxury Goods, ',
 '9876 - Leisure Products']
```

Comment: Yes, can you also briefly explain?

Comment: Sure, as we know that the pattern always starts with numerics (and that there are no other numbers in the string we want to capture). \d means one digit, \d+ means any number of digits, \D means one non digit. So \d+\D+ means any number of digits followed by any number of non-digits.