# split string by all non alphabetic character occurences in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to do the following function: We need to build a list out of a string. The list should only have alphabetical characters in it.

```
#if the input is the following string
mystring = "ashtray ol'god for,       shure!  i.have "

#the output should give a list like this:
mylist = ['ashtray','ol','god','for','shure','i','have']
```

No modules should be imported. I created the following function and it works, but I would be happy if someone could provide a better way to do it.

```
for ch in mystring:   
      if ch.isalpha() == False:
             mystring = mystring.replace(ch,' ') 
mylist = mystring.split()
```

by alphabetical character I mean all alphabetical characters present in UTF8, that means including arabic ,jewish chars etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string based on a pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534312/splitting-a-string-based-on-a-pattern-in-python)

Comment: Any "better" way would surely include importing modules. Is there any reason why you must avoid this? If this is some exercise, can you please provide the exact restrictions?

Comment: the rules are: not importing modules, not executing inputs, no global variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```py
mystring = "ashtray ol'god for,       shure!  i.have "

lst = []
mystr = ''
for i in mystring:
    temp = ord(i)
    if (65 <= temp <= 90) or (97 <= temp <= 122):
       mystr += i
    else:
        if mystr:
            lst.append(mystr)
            mystr = ''

print(lst)
```

Or

```py
mystring = "ashtray ol'god for,       shure!  i.have "

lst = []
mystr = ''
for i in mystring:
    if i in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
       mystr += i
    else:
        if mystr:
            lst.append(mystr)
            mystr = ''

print(lst)
```

Or (including Non-English characters)

```py
mystring = "ashtray ol'god for,       shure!  i.have "

lst = []
mystr = ''
for i in mystring:
    if i.isalpha():
        mystr += i
    else:
        if mystr:
            lst.append(mystr)
            mystr = ''

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['ashtray', 'ol', 'god', 'for', 'shure', 'i', 'have']
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: I mentioned this should be done without importing any module. Thank you.

Comment: @bogus edited the answer, and tell me if its not working...

Comment: It's a nice solution but I'ts my fault that I was not precise enough in my question: All alphabetical characters in UTF8, so arabic characters and all of that are included

Comment: @bogus tried some, but seems like the punctuation kinda characters are not alphabetic at all, is that okay for you? i will post the code in the answer and check it and tell whether if its okay or not

Comment: I'm just gonna replace in 'ABCDEFGHIJKL.... ' with isalpha() and use this, thank you

Comment: @bogus good choice

Comment: sorry just one more question that I have: after the else, that if mystr, is true only if mystr in not empty righ?

Comment: @bogus yes, cuz there's no need of empty strings actually for you right?

Comment: yes,that's right